# Regular procedure / method pointer

Tags: delphi, winapi

How can I define callback function of `timeSetEvent` as an instance method?

```
TUDPBC = class(TObject)                                         
private
  hTimer: word;
...
public
  procedure sendUDPBC;
...
end;

procedure DoTimer(uTimerID, uMessage: UINT; dwUser,dw1,dw2: DWORD); stdcall;

procedure TUDPBC.sendUDPBC;  //send UDP Broadcast
begin
...
  hTimer := TimeSetEvent(FTimeOut, uRes, DoTimer, 0, TIME_ONESHOT); //need DoTimer as a TUDPBC class method
...
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I define callback function of `timeSetEvent` as an instance method?

The simple answer is that you cannot. The signature of the callback is not something that you can vary. It is defined by the API and must be a [simple unbound procedure with this signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728861.aspx):

```
typedef void ( CALLBACK *LPTIMECALLBACK)(
   UINT      uTimerID,
   UINT      uMsg,
   DWORD_PTR dwUser,
   DWORD_PTR dw1,
   DWORD_PTR dw2
);
```

What you can do though is pass a pointer to `timeSetEvent` that contains the address of your instance. The pattern runs like this:

```
procedure TimeProcCallback(uTimerID, uMessage: UINT; dwUser,dw1,dw2: DWORD_PTR); stdcall;
begin
  TUDPBC(dwUser).TimeProc(uTimerID, uMessage);
end;
```

This is the callback that you pass to `timeSetEvent`. Your class would look like this:

```
type
  TUDPBC = class
  private
    FTimerID: MMRESULT;
    procedure TimeProc(uTimerID, uMessage: UINT);
  end;
```

This method of the class will be called by the callback function and so have access to the instance variables.

Set the timer like this:

```
FTimerID := timeSetEvent(TimeOut, uRes, TimeProcCallback, DWORD_PTR(Self), TIME_ONESHOT);
```

So, you pass the address of the instance in the `dwUser` argument. That is then passed on to your callback. That callback can, in turn, call an instance method.

Comment: So `dwUser` can be used to pass any value, which is passed back to you in the timer event. That way you can distinguish between timers. You can use that field to store a reference to your object in.